# multicols equations not aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, multicol

I'm trying to align two columns of equations but I don't know why it is not getting aligned horizontally. I know it isa small difference but I find it really annoying (I know my code is bad, if you have any comments, I'd be thankfull).

```
Analisando os dois pontos de equilíbrio ao mesmo tempo e fazendo comparações para os valores de $\mu = -1$, $\mu = -1$ e $\mu = 1$ tem-se:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\[
    (\overline{x_1},\overline{x_2}) = (\sqrt{\mu},  0)\\
\]
\[
    \begin{cases}
        \lambda_1 = -2\sqrt{\mu}\\
        \lambda_2 = -1
    \end{cases}
\]
\begin{align*}
    &(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = (-j2, -1), &x = -&1\\
    &(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = ( 0, -1), &x = & 0\\
    &(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = (-2, -1), &x = & 1
\end{align*}
\vfill
\[
    (\overline{x_1},\overline{x_2}) = (-\sqrt{\mu},  0)
\]
\[
    \begin{cases}
        \lambda_1 = 2\sqrt{\mu}\\
        \lambda_2 = -1
    \end{cases}    
\]
\begin{align*}
    &(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = (j2, -1), &x = -&1\\
    &(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = ( 0, -1), &x = & 0\\
    &(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = (2, -1), &x = & 1
\end{align*}
\vfill
\end{multicols}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is there any particular reason why you use  `multicols`?

Comment: No reason at all, it is just the way I thought it would work

Comment: also note that you should never have display math environments following each other so never `\]` followed by `\[` or `\begin{align}` with no intervening text.

Comment: I actually did that because I was having trouble breaking the line when I used any equation before the \begin{cases}. What would be the correct way to do that? (Thank you very much for the comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For horizontally aligning stuf, it generally is better to use two side-by-side minipages. I use `0.475\linewidth` because the minipages have a margin themselves, and if you use `0.5\linewidth` you will end up with an overfull hbox error.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
Analisando os dois pontos de equilíbrio ao mesmo tempo e fazendo comparações para os valores de $\mu = -1$, $\mu = -1$ e $\mu = 1$ tem-se:

\begin{minipage}{0.475\linewidth}
\[
    (\overline{x_1},\overline{x_2}) = (\sqrt{\mu},  0)\\
\]
\[
    \begin{cases}
        \lambda_1 = -2\sqrt{\mu}\\
        \lambda_2 = -1
    \end{cases}
\]
\begin{align*}
    (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= (-j2, -1), & x &= -1\\
    (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= ( 0, -1),  & x &= 0\\
    (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= (-2, -1),  & x &= 1
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.475\linewidth}
\[
    (\overline{x_1},\overline{x_2}) = (-\sqrt{\mu},  0)
\]
\[
    \begin{cases}
        \lambda_1 = 2\sqrt{\mu}\\
        \lambda_2 = -1
    \end{cases}    
\]
\begin{align*}
    (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= (j2, -1), & x &= -1\\
    (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= ( 0, -1), & x &= 0\\
    (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= (2, -1),  & x &= 1
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, you're fast lol. Thank you very much, your way even looks better (in both ways, code and text).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hand-made two column `align*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Analisando os dois pontos de equilíbrio ao mesmo tempo e 
fazendo comparações para os valores de $\mu = -1$, 
$\mu = -1$ e $\mu = 1$ tem-se:
\begin{align*}
&  (\overline{x_1},\overline{x_2}) = (\sqrt{\mu},  0)
&& (\overline{x_1},\overline{x_2}) = (-\sqrt{\mu},  0)
\\
& \begin{cases}
  \lambda_1 = -2\sqrt{\mu}\\
  \lambda_2 = -1
  \end{cases}
&&\begin{cases}
  \lambda_1 = 2\sqrt{\mu}\\
  \lambda_2 = -1
  \end{cases}    
\\
& \begin{aligned}[t]
  (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= (-j2, -1), & x &= -1
  \\
  (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= ( 0, -1),  & x &= 0
  \\
  (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= (-2, -1),  & x &= 1
  \end{aligned}
&&\begin{aligned}[t]
  (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= (j2, -1),  & x &= -1
  \\
  (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= ( 0, -1),  & x &= 0
  \\
  (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) &= (2, -1),   & x &= 1
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer (I didn't know the meaning of "&&", but I searched here and found you already answered other topic about that lol). In this case what would be the best or the most correct way of writing this equations, with this align* or with minipage as Max did in his answer?

Comment: @Marschall I would go with egreg's answer. Mine is more a quick fix.